# Issue with JupyterLab: Unexpected Behavior with Keyboard Shortcuts and "Click to Add a Cell" Button

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been encountering an issue while working with JupyterLab that I'm hoping someone might be able to help me resolve.

When I press the `j` key repeatedly, the `Click to add a cell` button appears unexpectedly. Following the appearance of this button, all keyboard shortcuts seem to be disabled. This is causing a significant disruption to my workflow, as I rely heavily on these shortcuts for efficiency.

I'm looking for a way to either:

1. Prevent the `Click to add a cell` button from appearing when the `j` key is pressed repeatedly, or
2. Enable the keyboard shortcuts again after the button has appeared.
   I've tried searching for solutions or similar issues online, but haven't been able to find anything that addresses this specific problem. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, I'm currently using JupyterLab version 4.0.2 and Python 3.10.4.

Thank you in advance for your help!